# How can I convert select list items to lowercase in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to convert a select list (which is populated by a data feed) into lower case, I have traced as far some code in the relevant controller;

```
private SelectList getAddressCountriesListDD()
{
    var addressCountries = myOPG.AddressCountries;
    return new SelectList(addressCountries, "key", "value", "GBR");
}
```

The myopg part is the datafeed, I need to get the selectlist into lowercase.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
var addressCountries = myOPG.AddressCountries;
```

with

```
var addressCountries = myOPG.AddressCountries
                            .Select(c => c.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
```

Answer (score 0):

if addressCountries is a list of strings, then something like this (using LINQ).....

```
var lcase = from c in addressCountries
select c.ToLower();
```